# Delete a text in a row of a column if it doesn't start with date in R

Tags: r, date, design-patterns, find

I have an output from R with three columns. I'm trying to identify if the content of the cell in one column (sc2) starts with date, if not I'd like to delete the string in that column.

```
Case_Number "Comment Date"  sc2
1???????    2018-06-19      Hi Kara, This is reference to your case no
1???????    2018-06-19      EXPECTED RESULTS: Date field on contact (S0 Last Campa...
1???????    2018-06-19      6/22/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM CST
1???????    2018-06-19      followup on friday followup on friday
1???????    2018-06-19      Hi Kandepi, Thank you for your response
1???????    2018-06-19      06/25/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM CST?
1???????    2018-06-19      Tier 3 Update from Chatter:: @[??????? ???????kar] Why ar...
1???????    2018-06-19      Hi lesha, I checked all the possibilities but was unable t...
1???????    2018-06-19      Hi Sarah, This is ??????? ???????li following up on behalf ...
1???????    2018-06-19      6/22/2018 between 12:00 PM 02:00 PM EST Friday
1???????    2018-06-19      06/21/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM PST
1???????    2018-06-19      06/20/2018 between 10:00 AM and 12:00 PM EST
```

[Current R Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYuQP.png)

I'm still a learner, tried using a function to find date pattern and replace it with " "

```
del <- function(x, del){

   for (i in 1:nrow(fstat))
{
   datepat <- "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9])"

   datedetect <-str_detect(sc3,datepat) 

  if (fstat$sc3[i]== FALSE)
 {
   fstat$sc3 <- " "
 }
 }

 }
```

The code I tried maynot be perfect,but as I said, I'm a new learner.

[Expected R Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPpQP.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: gave test data as text, as it should be

Comment: Thanks @Armali, I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The approach with a `for` loop doesn't take advantage of R's vector operations.
- In order *to delete the string*, I recommend setting it to `NA` with `is.na(fstat$sc2) = …`.

Your goal can be achieved with a one-line statement:

```
> fstat$sc2
 [1] Hi Kara, This is reference to your case no                    
 [2] EXPECTED RESULTS: Date field on contact (S0 Last Campa...     
 [3] 6/22/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM CST                     
 [4] followup on friday followup on friday                         
 [5] Hi Kandepi, Thank you for your response                       
 [6] 06/25/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM CST?                   
 [7] Tier 3 Update from Chatter:: @[??????? ???????kar] Why ar...  
 [8] Hi lesha, I checked all the possibilities but was unable t... 
 [9] Hi Sarah, This is ??????? ???????li following up on behalf ...
[10] 6/22/2018 between 12:00 PM 02:00 PM EST Friday                
[11] 06/21/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM PST                    
[12] 06/20/2018 between 10:00 AM and 12:00 PM EST                  
12 Levels: 06/20/2018 between 10:00 AM and 12:00 PM EST ...
> is.na(fstat$sc2) = is.na(as.Date(fstat$sc2, "%m/%d/%Y"))
> fstat$sc2
 [1] <NA>                                          
 [2] <NA>                                          
 [3] 6/22/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM CST     
 [4] <NA>                                          
 [5] <NA>                                          
 [6] 06/25/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM CST?   
 [7] <NA>                                          
 [8] <NA>                                          
 [9] <NA>                                          
[10] 6/22/2018 between 12:00 PM 02:00 PM EST Friday
[11] 06/21/2018 between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM PST    
[12] 06/20/2018 between 10:00 AM and 12:00 PM EST  
12 Levels: 06/20/2018 between 10:00 AM and 12:00 PM EST ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Armali, this worked!! One liner.. helped me with my week's confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function, untested, without an example dataset.

```
del <- function(DF, datecol = 2, delcol = 3){
  datepat <- "^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"
  inx <- stringr::str_detect(DF[[datecol]], datepat)
  DF[[delcol]][inx] <- ""
  DF
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rui the output still remains unchanged. i.e. the strings without date as starting word still remains. Appreciate the help!